# QFontMetrics leave extra space between lines

Tags: python, fonts, pyside6

I'm trying to draw multiple paragraphs of text with PySide6's `QPainter` and `QFontMetrics`. I want to draw them with the same spacing as they would have if I drew them all in a single block of text, but the line spacing isn't quite right.

In the following example, the font metrics say that the font's line spacing is 17. When I measure a single line of text, the bounding rectangle is indeed 17 pixels high. However, when I measure two lines of text, the bounding rectangle is 35 pixels high, not 34. Where does the extra pixel come from, and can I see it on some property of the font or the font metrics?

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QFont, QFontMetrics
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
font = QFont()
metrics = QFontMetrics(font)
print(metrics.lineSpacing())  # 17
print(metrics.boundingRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 'A').height())  # 17
print(metrics.boundingRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 'A\nB').height())  # 35 != 17 * 2
print(metrics.leading())  # 0
print(metrics.ascent())  # 14
print(metrics.descent())  # 3
```

By the way, it isn't always one extra pixel. If I make the font bigger, the extra space increases.

### Update

I thought I had figured this out with [musicamante's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248856/4794) of switching from `QFontMetrics` to `QFontMetricsF`, but there's still a difference.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QFont, QFontMetricsF
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
font = QFont()
metrics = QFontMetricsF(font)
print(metrics.height())  # 16.8125
print(metrics.boundingRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100),
                           0,
                           'A').getCoords())  # (0.0, 0.0, 9.9375, 16.8125)
print(metrics.boundingRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100),
                           0,
                           'A\nB').getCoords())  # (0.0, 0.0, 9.9375, 34.8125)
# Note the height of that rect doesn't match the next calculation.
print(metrics.height() + metrics.lineSpacing())  # 34.046875

# I can't see any combination of these numbers that makes 34.8125
print(metrics.lineSpacing())  # 17.234375
print(metrics.leading())  # 0.421875
print(metrics.ascent())  # 13.984375
print(metrics.descent())  # 2.828125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the height of a bounding rect of a font metrics doesn't depend on the characters used, but on the font specifications.

Two lines of text don't have the double of the `height()` of the bounding rect of a single line: instead, you have to consider the [`lineSpacing()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#lineSpacing).

In practice, the height of a bounding rect is normally the sum of:

- the [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#height) multiplied the number of lines;
- the [`leading()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#leading) multiplied by the number of spaces between the lines (aka: number of lines - 1);

Or, similarly, the sum of:

- the [`ascent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#ascent);
- the `lineSpacing()` multiplied by the number of spaces between lines;
- the [`descent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#descent);

Note that, obviously, the number of lines depends on the input text and the given options, for instance, if word wrapping was enabled and any of the source lines didn't fit the given source rectangle.

Also consider that most fonts are vectorial, meaning that their coordinates and metrics are proportional and in floating point values. QFontMetrics, instead, works with integer values for simplicity and optimization reasons, so you might get inconsistent results caused by rounding in cases for which the point size doesn't give rounded values: non integer numbers are generally "floored" (like `int()` in python).
In your case, the `leading` is probably more than 0 (but still less than 1), so you don't get a proper sum of the aforementioned heights.

Specifically, `QFontMetrics.boundingRect()` returns a QRect resulting by the [`QRectF.toAlignedRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrectf.html#toAlignedRect) of the computed formatted text, which is always "the smallest possible integer rectangle that completely contains this rectangle".

If you need to get precise coordinates, you need to use [QFontMetricsF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html), which is the floating point counterpart of the default basic QFontMetrics.

That said, if you plan on drawing formatted text with QPainter, then consider using QTextDocument or, at least, [QTextLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextlayout.html), which is consistent with the standard Qt text drawing and is generally faster, more reliable and "simpler" (well, once you get to know it). While it might seem a bit too complex than required, it's actually what Qt does when calling `boundingRect()`, so if you need custom painting, the QTextLayout option is actually better, especially if you can combine it with some smart caching (see QPicture) to avoid the common python bottleneck.

Comment: I thought that `QFontMetricsF` was the solution, but when I looked closer, I found that there's still a difference I can't explain. I've added a `QFontMetricsF` example to the question. Thanks for getting me this far, anyway. I think I can calculate a correction amount, at least.

Comment: @DonKirkby I believe I found the reason: QTextLayout always aligns baselines on *whole* pixels (which makes sense), using ceil. It seems to coincide with your result: `ceil(ascent + descent + leading) + ascent + descent` results in 34.8125. You can see where the `qt_format_text` function (used to lay out text before returning the rectangle) does that in the [QPainter](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpainter.cpp.html) source code, starting around line #7660 (the `while (1)` loop).

Comment: I think you're right. The formula I found for the height of the bounds rectangle for `n` lines of text is `(n - 1) * math.ceil(metrics.lineSpacing()) + metrics.height()`. Curiously, it doesn't matter whether the top of the rectangle is on a whole pixel or not.

Comment: @DonKirkby What do you mean with the last phrase?

Comment: I would have thought the `ceil()` would be applied to keep the whole pixels at the vertical position in each glyph where the font designer intended them to be. Now that I think about it, though, I guess it makes sense. The way it is, the vertical positions are consistent between lines, but the programmer can adjust that position by changing the top of the rectangle. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @DonKirkby Well, yes, the intended result is to have *consistent* behavior across lines based on the source rectangle, no matter its origin coordinates: the text is laid out on an abstract (0, 0)-based layout (only using its size as reference for wrapping), and then aligned to the given rectangle while eventually adjusting the new computed size. I'll probably update the answer with these new findings. And, you're welcome, I thank you back: dealing with this was useful for me too :-)